# WSO2 IS - Enable Mobile Number Verification when number is updated

Tags: wso2, sms, wso2-identity-server

We are trying to use the Mobile Number verification on Mobile number update with WSO2 Identity Server (v5.11.0) as per [this guide](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/enable-verification-for-updated-mobile-number/), while the SMS OTP is being sent, it is being sent to the old mobile number.

Example:
User with mobile number 111111

We are sending the request to the SCIM2.0 API **https://hostname/scim2/Me** to update the mobile number with the following request:

```
{
   "schemas":[
      "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
   ],
   "Operations":[
      {
         "op":"replace",
         "value":{
            "phoneNumbers":[
               {
                  "type":"mobile",
                  "value":"222222"
               }
            ],
            "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User":{
               "verifyMobile":true
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The SMS OTP is being sent to the old mobile number (111111) instead of the new one (222222)

The guide clearly states:

> When a user updates their mobile number in the user profile, an SMS OTP is sent to the new mobile number.

Is there another way to configure that functionality, are we missing a step ? or should the request be modified for us to have the correct behavior?

PS: The server is configured as per the guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in the sample event publisher, the number to which the SMS is sent is defined as `"to"={{mobile}}`. This will pick the existing mobile number persisted under the claim `http://wso2.org/claims/mobile`. Change that value as `to"={{send-to}}`. Then it will send the SMS to the verification pending mobile number. The updated sample event publisher should be as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventPublisher name="HTTPOutputEventAdapter" processing="enable"
    statistics="disable" trace="disable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventpublisher">
    <from streamName="id_gov_sms_notify_stream" version="1.0.0"/>
    <mapping customMapping="enable" type="json">
        <inline>{"api_key"="xxxxxx",
            "api_secret"="xxxxxxxx",
            "from"="NEXMO",
            "to"={{send-to}},
            "text"={{body}}
            }</inline>
    </mapping>
    <to eventAdapterType="http">
        <property name="http.client.method">httpPost</property>
        <property name="http.url">https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json</property>
    </to>
</eventPublisher>
```

Comment: Thank you, fixed it in the event publisher and it worked like a charm.
(Weird enough this info should have been clarified in the documentation)